# GoogleTest RUN_ALL_TESTS Doesn't Seem to be Working

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

When I run a GoogleTest executable I create, with two tests, I get the following output not matter what the pass or fail result of each test is:

```
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
```

Main_TestAll.C:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Env_Test.C:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include <Environment.h>

class EnvTest : public ::testing::Test
{
  protected:
    virtual void SetUp()
    {
    }

    virtual void TearDown()
    {
    }
}

TEST_F(EnvTest, getValue1)
{
    const char *one = "1";

    Environment *myEnv = new Environment("./default.cfg");
    myEnv->setValue("general", "foo", one);
    EXPECT_STREQ(one, myEnv->getValue("foo"));
}

TEST_F(EnvTest, getValue2)
{
    const char *two = "2";

    Environment *myEnv = new Environment("./default.cfg");
    myEnv->setValue("general", "foo", two);
    EXPECT_STREQ(two, myEnv->getValue("foo"));
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(tools_environment_test)

include_directories(
    ${Environment_SOURCE_DIR}
)

set(GTESTSRCS
    Main_TestAll.C
    Env_Test.C
   )

add_getest_test(Env
    ${GTESTSRCS}
    )

add_library(Env
   ${GTESTSRCS}
   )
```

add_getest_test is a macro we use for compiling and linking gtests.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try replacing your macro with a plain `add_executable` and see if you get your tests run. Then you can narrow the source of the problem. Otherwise, it looks weird that you have what looks like two targets with the same name, i.e. a library and an executable.

Comment: add `TEST(A,B) {}` to your Main_TestAll.C and see what happens...

Comment: Thanks PiotrNycz!  That did the trick.